# using a regex in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying my first serious project in `jsoup` and I've got stuck in this matter-

I'm trying to get zipcodes from a site. There is a list of zipcodes.

Here is one of the lines that presents the zipcode-

```
<td align="center"><a href="http://www.zipcodestogo.com/Hialeah/FL/33011/">33011</a></td>
```

So the idea I've got is going through the page and getting all the strings that contain 6 digits from 1-9. Regex is `^[0-9]{6,6}$`

code was -

```
doc.select("td:matchesOwn(^[0-9]{5,5}$)");
```

but nothing came out. I can't find the way to get these zipcodes out of that site.... 
Does anyone know how to do it?

the real question here is how do i get the numbers that are not in any tags,but just written out in the open (i guess there is a term for that but im not that good with xml terms)

Comment: `:matchesOwn(regex) - elements whose own text matches the specified regular expression. The text must appear in the found element, not any of its descendants.`

Comment: nice quote , really helped me.
now can you help me find the solution for my problem?

Comment: OT: The value between <a href=...> and </a> is called the *element content*.

Comment: If you want to *get the numbers that are not in any tags* then you can just get the document as a string and search numbers using some regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `Element#getElementsMatchingOwnText`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String html = "<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"http://www.zipcodestogo.com/Hialeah/FL/33011/\">33011</a></td> ";
    final Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(html).getElementsMatchingOwnText("^[0-9]{5,5}$");

    for (final Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println("element = [" + element + "]");
        System.out.println("zip = [" + element.text() + "]");
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
element = [<a href="http://www.zipcodestogo.com/Hialeah/FL/33011/">33011</a>]
zip = [33011]
```

Comment: great solution! ive already created a really long code that was about to work when you posted this short and proper solution. thank you!